# Chrome refuses to use HTTP/2 for fetch upload while using streams

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, fetch-api

Currently trying to create a simple file upload application, I'm using S3 as the storage and presigned-url to do the upload from the client-side.

The application is built using SvelteKit and using Fetch for uploading.

```
const duplex = { duplex: 'half' };

const response = await fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: file.stream(),
  headers: {
  'Content-Type': file.type
  },
  signal: this.abortController?.signal,
  ...duplex
});
```

When running the app in Firefox, it uploads normally, when attempting to run it on chrome, it gets interrupted with the Quic/Http/2 error `net::ERR_H2_OR_QUIC_REQUIRED`

Both were running on localhost with Http. I assumed that chrome had some extra protections against running this type of upload through a non SSL channel, so I tried to deploy the app and run it over HTTPS, still it worked on firefox and not on chrome.

Edit:

This seems to be an issue specific to s3 pre signed urls not working nicely with the H2/QUIC requirement from chrome, firefox works because it has more lenient rules regarding this. My conclusion is that for now, I'm going to do the check bellow to still have stream-uploading where it is available, but I'm giving up on getting it to work on chrome.

Quick code snippet showing how to verify if the browser will allow uploading with Fetch-stream to "less secure" urls

```js
// Decide if we are going to upload using stream or normal arrayBuffer
if (navigator.connection?.effectiveType === '4g') {
    opt.duplex = 'half';
    opt.body = file.stream();
} else {
    opt.body = file;
}
```

Comment: Upload streaming is working on Chromium 124. What happens when you type lower case letters in the `<input>` in this plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/2PQK21kZTZvZ2oVi?preview? I think you want to use `text/plain` as the `Content-Type`.

Comment: @guest271314 the letters get streamed and shown as uppercase on the plnkr, with text/plain it still errors on chrome and works on firefox, I tried using a simpler stream instead of a file, so I followed the original chrome dev blog example found at https://developer.chrome.com/docs/capabilities/web-apis/fetch-streaming-requests but still, the same thing happens

Comment: Hi. `QUIC Protocol` can be mandatory and maybe you disabled it on Chrome (the `default` value is `enabled`. You should check in `chrome://flags/` that it is **not disabled**.

Comment: I also thought that QUIC might be disabled, but it definitively is enabled in the flags.

Comment: What is your web / proxy server ?

Comment: _"the letters get streamed and shown as uppercase on the plnkr, with text/plain"_ Then upload streaming is working. That is the edge case of full-duplex streaming between a `ServiceWorker` and a `WindowClient` on Chromium based browsers. Other than that case no browser supports full duplex streaming, see https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/1254. I use a Native Messaging host and `deno` or `node` for full-duplex streaming to and from the browser https://github.com/guest271314/native-messaging-deno/tree/fetch-duplex.

Comment: What does your server look like?

Comment: Here's a Deno server and code you can run in DevTools console to test half-duplex streaming  https://gist.github.com/guest271314/4847c70be203ee7cd4c8a6d6a9bca1d3. Here's a Deno server for full-duplex streaming  I use with Native Messaging to facilate usage in the browser https://gist.github.com/guest271314/d20b2a2924d0e2e0c333c01d8b8acace. Upload streaming has been supported for a while on Chromium based browsers. I'm on 124 Developer Build and am able to upload stream. Something else must be going on.

Comment: @ThomasReichmann The URL is my Deno Deploy endpoint that I use for full-duplex streaming as I linked to above. What happens when you do this in DevTools `console`? `fetch("https://comfortable-deer-52.deno.dev",{method:"post",body:new File(["a"], "file.txt").stream(),duplex: "half"}).then((r => r.text())).then(console.log).catch(console.error);`?

Comment: @guest271314 Got a lot of insight from that snippet, so apparently that snippet runs on the sveltekit application just fine, so something is wrong with my payload or the presigned url that I'm using, I'll do some extra debugging when I get the time and post back here any insights I get

Answer (score -1):

It's simple as you go, Use HTTPS url instead of HTTP url.

Comment: I mentioned in the last part of the question, I've tried deploying the application and running it with HTTPS but it still ends up working on firefox and failing with the same message on chrome. This happens on multiple devices.